# Xamarin VS 15: Deploy Failing to Emulator (unknown provider)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am attempting to debug a Xamarin App, the emulator is configured as follows:

Name: Nexus_5_6_x86

Device: Nexus 5

Target: Android 6.0 - API Level 23

CPU/ABI: Intel Atom (x86)

RAM: 1024

VM Heap: 768

Internal Storage: 1000

The VM runs fine if I start it directly from AVD. However attempting to debug the app results in the following error:

Emulator Nexus_5_6_x86 cannot be started with VS (unknown provider).

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for this...

Make sure the emulator is running ahead of time.  Start it from the AVD Manager.

It's not clear what your development environment is, but I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community with Xamarin.  I was having this problem, until I started VS as administrator.

I've also read about some workarounds involving 'skylake' (Intel's newer processes from 2013 on wards, if I recall correctly)

Alternatively, you can debug / test using a different emulator environment, such as:

- Genymotion XAP
- Xamarin Android Player

For Build / Deploy output, set the logging to the most detailed to find additional information on the issue.

Hope this helps someone along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and solved the issue by

1. Stop the emulator.
2. Kill the VSHub process(es) via Task Manager.
3. Restart the emulator.

I could then deploy and run the application again.